# Search all tables, all columns for a specific value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a specific value, let's say string 'comments'.  I need to find all instances of this in the database as I need to do an update on the format to change it to (*) Comments.

How can I do this? The database is in SQL Server 2000 format.

Comment: you can do that very simply with phpmyadmin

Comment: You can find the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42714042/1820880

Answer (score 375, accepted):

I've just updated my blog post to correct the error in the script that you were having Jeff, you can see the updated script here: [Search all fields in SQL Server Database](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated)

As requested, here's the script in case you want it but I'd recommend reviewing the blog post as I do update it from time to time

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = '## YOUR STRING HERE ##'
 
 
-- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
-- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
-- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
-- Updated and tested by Tim Gaunt
-- http://www.thesitedoctor.co.uk
-- http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx
-- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2010
-- Date modified: 03rd March 2011 19:00 GMT
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
 
SET NOCOUNT ON
 
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
 
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
 
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )
 
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
         
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
 
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
         
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END   
END
 
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
 
DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: Actually, I tried the solution in your blog post (it has a minor error), but it somehow always returns the same result. See my comment in your blog post.

Comment: Thanks Abel, I've been meaning to get around to fix that, I've put up two flavours, one which can be run on it's own without creating a stored procedure, the other is a re-usable stored procedure that once you've added to your db you can re-run anytime you want.

Hope it helps.

Tim

Comment: Great script, Tim. I just added uniqueidentifier support to suit my needs, but it still works as a charm.

Comment: anthares, what changes are required for uniqueidentifier support?

Comment: @BrianAdkins it should just be a matter of changing the line:
`AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')`

to:
`AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal', 'uniqueidentifier')`

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Tim Service Unavailable

Comment: 6 years later, the blog is unavailable.  Please post code directly in the answer.

Comment: @AndyMcKenna it was just a temporary server issue, the blog post is still there. I didn't originall paste in the full code snippet as I've updated it several times since :)

Comment: Blog post is a dead link

Comment: The code is above but here's an updated link, not sure why the rewrites aren't working: http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated

Comment: This code worked for me exactly as advertised... however it ran for 4 hours in my work environment (large(ish) data)

Comment: @ColinMac
You are welcome to try my code and please let me know whether it returns faster. https://wordpress.com/stats/post/190/fullparam.wordpress.com

Comment: @regeter Thanks but I can't open that link

Comment: So many years later and I always come back to this post. It's helped me TREMENDOUSLY in locating strings of data in massive databases. Thank you @Tim and Narayana!

Comment: @Tim thank but it show me ???? in ColumnValue

Comment: I given tump-up just want to say the code works for me billion of time thanks this is what coding is all about sharing knowledge well done

Answer (score 108):

I published one here: [FullParam SQL Blog](http://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/)

```
/* Reto Egeter, fullparam.wordpress.com */

DECLARE @SearchStrTableName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255), @SearchStrInXML bit, @FullRowResult bit, @FullRowResultRows int
SET @SearchStrColumnValue = '%searchthis%' /* use LIKE syntax */
SET @FullRowResult = 1
SET @FullRowResultRows = 3
SET @SearchStrTableName = NULL /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrColumnName = NULL /* NULL for all columns, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrInXML = 0 /* Searching XML data may be slow */

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), ColumnValue nvarchar(max),ColumnType nvarchar(20))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = '',@ColumnName nvarchar(128),@ColumnType nvarchar(20), @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(110), @QuotedSearchStrColumnName nvarchar(110)
SET @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue = QUOTENAME(@SearchStrColumnValue,'''')
DECLARE @ColumnNameTable TABLE (COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128),DATA_TYPE nvarchar(20))

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND TABLE_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName,TABLE_NAME)
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
    )
    IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),DATA_TYPE
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN (' + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchStrColumnValue,'%',''),'_',''),'[',''),']',''),'-','')) = 1 THEN '''tinyint'',''int'',''smallint'',''bigint'',''numeric'',''decimal'',''smallmoney'',''money'',' ELSE '' END + '''char'',''varchar'',''nchar'',''nvarchar'',''timestamp'',''uniqueidentifier''' + CASE @SearchStrInXML WHEN 1 THEN ',''xml''' ELSE '' END + ')
                AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE COALESCE(' + CASE WHEN @SearchStrColumnName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '''' + @SearchStrColumnName + '''' END  + ',COLUMN_NAME)'
        INSERT INTO @ColumnNameTable
        EXEC (@sql)
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM @ColumnNameTable)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @ColumnName
            SELECT TOP 1 @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME,@ColumnType = DATA_TYPE FROM @ColumnNameTable
            SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @ColumnName + ''',' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'LEFT(CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 4096),''' 
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + '),'''
            ELSE 'LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 4096),''' END + @ColumnType + ''' 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC(@sql)
            IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 IF @FullRowResult = 1 
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@FullRowResultRows AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ''' + @TableName + ''' AS [TableFound],''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS [ColumnFound],''FullRow>'' AS [FullRow>],*' +
                    ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
                EXEC(@sql)
            END
            DELETE FROM @ColumnNameTable WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
        END 
    END
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM #Results
GROUP BY TableName, ColumnName, ColumnValue, ColumnType
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly for me. Much faster compared to the 'SearchAllTables' procedure found in this thread.

Comment: Tim's answer does not seem to not find values in columns of type numeric whereas this answer does (albeit taking longer)

Comment: Significant achievement: not only it's much faster, but also looks into more data types and presentation is excellent. Thank you

Comment: Worked for me also for uniqueidentifier while the other solution didn't...

Comment: this query worked for me . thank you :-)

Comment: Is there a beginn/end block missing. I got the error: 'Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'DECLARE '

Comment: This works really well and is fast. It helped me find the location of the data I was after.

Answer (score 7):

The below Query works but very slow... copied from [vyaskn.tripod.com](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm)

```
Declare @SearchStr nvarchar(100)

SET  @SearchStr='Search String' BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128),
 @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)  SET  @TableName = ''    SET @SearchStr2 =
 QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL    
BEGIN       
  SET @ColumnName = ''      
  SET @TableName =  (
    SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' +
    QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
      OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)),
        'IsMSShipped') = 0)

  WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)      
  BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = (
      SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
        AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
      AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
      AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)
      IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL            
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #Results
      EXEC
      (
        'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + 
          ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
        ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
      )             
      END       
    END     
  END

  SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results END
```

Answer (score 6):

You could query the sys.tables database view to get out the names of the tables, and then use this query to build yourself another query to do the update on the back of that.  For instance:

```
select 'select * from '+name from sys.tables
```

will give you a script that will run a select * against all the tables in the system catalog, you could alter the string in the select clause to do your update, as long as you know the column name is the same on all the tables you wish to update, so your script would look something like:

```
select 'update '+name+' set comments = ''(*)''+comments where comments like ''%comment to be updated%'' ' from sys.tables
```

You could also then predicate on the tables query to only include tables that have a name in a certain format, or are in a subset you want to create the update script for.

Comment: This question was for SQL Server 2000. There's no Sys object in this SQL version. "Invalid object name 'sys.tables'"