# Find a value in all databases in a database server

Tags: database

I need a stored procedure to search for a string in any database in a database server. For Eg there are 5 databases in a database server and i want to search for string "sooraj" in all tables of all databases in that server. Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Thanks
Sooraj

Comment: Which Database server are you using?

Comment: Just Google it, this has been covered in a million places for all DBMS' out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [search all tables, all columns for a specific value SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796506/search-all-tables-all-columns-for-a-specific-value-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Several database servers allow to define an "alias" which points to another database. So what you could do:

1. Create aliases for all databases in one server
2. Get a list of all relevant tables in your stored procedure
3. Search the tables