# Search all tables that contains a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search for all tables and columns containing  specific value .

Like ,

```
Select * from [All_Tables] where [AnyColumn] = 'MyValue'
```

Comment: This was asked before [here][1]; the referenced script should work for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796506/search-all-tables-all-columns-for-a-specific-value-sql-server

Comment: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PL/SQl tool, then you can search for the object that you are looking for. The tool provides the gui wherein you can enter the keyword you are looking for. 
Say, in your case, search for 'MyValue'.