# Is there a way to search the fields of all tables at once, in SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I was hoping that within the WebMatrix (C#.net) environment (using SQL Server Compact) that there was a way to search all tables and fields for a value.  I have a bunch (like 100) of tables, connected to via WebMatrix and I am trying to look for a table that holds some information I need.

I have been here:  http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2007/11/02/How+To+Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database.aspx

And here, on stackoverflow:  [search all tables, all columns for a specific value SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796506/search-all-tables-all-columns-for-a-specific-value-sql-server)

As well as here:  [How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Unfortunately I am not seeing how to implement these methods in my current environment, but I realize there may not really be a way to do what I am asking.

Whether there is or there isn't a way to do what I'm asking, I would at least like to know, so I can look for another method.

Thanks!

-----------------------------SQL SubQuery That Works In SQL CE-----------------------------

> SELECT * FROM UserProfile JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles
>   ON UserProfile.UserID = webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId
>   WHERE (RoleId <> 6) AND Email NOT IN
>   (SELECT Email FROM UserProfile JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles
>    ON UserProfile.UserID = webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId
>    WHERE RoleId = 6) ORDER BY Email

Comment: What version of SQL Server CE are you using?

Comment: How are you "trying to look for a table"? What are you "not seeing"? Every one of those links seem to do what you asked; have you tried them? What happened? SQL CE itself should be able to do what you want, why must you go through WebMatrix?

Comment: @CameronTinker I hope this answers your question, but I am using WebMatrix 2, if that helps.

Comment: I always use WebMatrix - For Web Apps, that is

Comment: @CameronTinker I haven't really tried because I don't know how to query them. Can you use a wildcard in the FROM clause?

Comment: The only reason I ask about your SQL CE version is that there are new functions introduced in SQL CE 4.0 that are not available in SQL CE 3.5.

Comment: @CameronTinker Let me see if I can find out. One sec...

Comment: @CameronTinker It is SQL CE 4.0

Comment: I am looking into a solution for querying without needing to create tables. This will be less efficient however.

Comment: @CameronTinker That is fine, performance will not be an issue. I won't have to do it very often at all.

Comment: Do you have access to the database file itself? It seems that SQL CE is very limited in what can be done in querying. Perhaps if you have access to the database file itself, you can write a small app to iterate through the result sets.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25562/discussion-between-cameron-tinker-and-voidking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've adapted the SQL from Syn123's answer and here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c 
       INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables AS t ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE  (c.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext')) AND (t.TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE')
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't do subqueries with SQL CE and thus can't select from a result set. If you have access to your .MDF database file, you can write a small console app to search for a particular keyword using the set returned by the above SQL. You need a way to create dynamic SQL and SQL CE doesn't support EXEC so this is difficult and most likely not possible by itself.

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLCESearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchText("Nancy");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SearchText(string searchText)
        {
            string connStr = "Data Source=Northwind40.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME ";
                sql += "FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c ";
                sql += "INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables AS t ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME ";
                sql += "WHERE  (c.DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext')) AND (t.TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE') ";

                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, connStr);
                da.Fill(dt);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string dynSQL = "SELECT [" + dr["COLUMN_NAME"] + "]";
                    dynSQL += " FROM [" + dr["TABLE_NAME"] + "]";
                    dynSQL += " WHERE [" + dr["COLUMN_NAME"] + "] LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";

                    DataTable result = new DataTable();
                    da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(dynSQL, connStr);
                    da.Fill(result);
                    foreach (DataRow r in result.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Table Name: " + dr["TABLE_NAME"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Column Name: " + dr["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + r[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

There's a really quick and dirty console application that will print out any table/column that contains a value of text. You can adapt it to fit your needs. I hope this helps.

Comment: I will update my post with an example I KNOW works that is used in a web application on a regular basis.

Comment: I'm interested to see how you achieved subqueries with SQL CE :). I've seen some solutions use joins, but that's really inefficient for a dataset as large as yours.

Comment: Okay, it's posted, but maybe I am oversimplifying what you mean by subQuery, because this is an example from SQL Server (non CE) I didn't even modify it for CE. Anyway, it is 5 where I am and I have to go, but I will return to this post first thing tomorrow morning (I get to work at 8 (CST)) Thanks again, see you tomorrow!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help as I can.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example console application that will spit out table\column info for any found text. I hope that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25571/discussion-between-cameron-tinker-and-voidking)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about CE, but I use this method:

http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/972792-find-text-string-database.html

namely the third one down.  Read and understand the syntax as you use it, it's highly modifiable and can filter by data type.

Comment: Thank you for your example, and please forgive this question if it is a dumb one, but I am familiar with sql querying (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...) and such. In the example in the link you posted, is that just a sql query? If so, it has some keywords in it that I have never seen before. If not, what language is it?

Comment: It's a MS SQL query that uses a cursor to loop through SQL system tables, I'm sure it can be made more legible.  The big question with my answer is will it work in CE, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I would love to try this method, but I'm not sure I understand enough about the syntax to modify it for use with my database. Certainly it can't be as simple as a copy/paste, can it?

Comment: Also, another error that I see is that I will not be allowed to Create_Table because we have read-only access from this end.

Comment: you shouldddd be able to create temp tables, so follow http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables and add a # in front of the query.  It's as simple as copy paste and then put your value into the Sargable, so the line SELECT Sargable = 'Beer'
is the one you'd replace the string on with your search term

Comment: I tried what you said, but I get another error: Invalid object name 'myTable99'. After putting the "#" in front of "myTable99"

Comment: Declare statements are not supported by SQL CE. Also, temp tables don't exist in SQL CE.

Comment: @Syn123 Well, I guess that means I'm probably out of options :(  Thank you so much for trying to help. At least I know now.

Comment: Don't give up yet. I've almost figured something out.

Comment: @CameronTinker Okay, I won't, Thank you so much for helping! If it helps any further, this is not something I even need a 'coded' solution for inherently. The thing is I think I am pulling data from the wrong table somewhere, and need to check to see if another table has these values (But there are hundreds! probably close to if not exceeding a thousand, or maybe even more, I stopped counting at 200 in the "b's"). I really only need to find this table once. No one else seems to know anything about its contents, because it is 3rd party software.

Comment: @CameronTinker Just realized that was you up there that told me that SQL CE doesn't support declare statements or temp tables. Sry about that.

Comment: That's unfortunate, well if you ever need the solution for MS SQL, it'll be here.  It does sound like Cameron is aware of the version specific nuances of CE, what the guy in my link is going is creating a base table of all the tables in the database and then iterating through them with a like clause on the value you're seeking returning all positive matches.

Comment: No problem. I will have an answer for you shortly.

Comment: @CameronTinker Great! If you come up with a solution, don't forget to post as an answer so I can accept :)