# How to implement search on all the tables of the database of SQL Server via asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, search, full-text-search, search-engine

My database has hundred of tables. I want to implement an optimized search on my database via front-hand such that there is only one search text-box and any string entered in the text-box is searched in all the tables and returns the relevant results.

For example I have tables like

```
MemberInfo, SpouseInfo, ChildrenInfo, OccupationInfo..
```

If in text-box a user enter a name than it checks that name in all the table and than returns all the result whether that name is of member itself or of its spouse or children.

I want to implement search on all the tables of my database build in Microsoft SQL Server via asp.net with c#

Comment: You tagged your question with full-text search. Why don't you try that? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008