# How to search about a specific value in all columns in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, search

I have a table (`students_all`) that contains 4 columns as below :-

- student_name
- age
- student_id
- class

Now how can I search about a specific value such as `'left'` in all columns in one query using **SQL Server 2008**.

I mean how can make something like Excel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to find any value in all columns.

Comment: First you need to tag SQL Server not MySQL. They are different. Second, you need to be more specific about how you need to query your table. There is nothing like ctrl + f in excel.

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE column1 = 'left' OR column2 = 'left' OR ...`

Comment: SQL is all about *structured* data - in which the (implied) type of data in each column is different. As such, there aren't many tools to assist with querying *across* columns (because such comparisons are usually meaningless). Your reference to Excel may be telling here - despite superficial similarities, tables in SQL are nothing like worksheets in Excel. If you find yourself struggling to do things that you could easily do in Excel, perhaps you've picked the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways to check to find something like that in one SQL for a special table, So I suggest this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM students_all
WHERE student_name + age + student_id + class LIKE '%left%';
```

---

But for a dynamic way I use this:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = 'Table_1';
DECLARE @Find nvarchar(50) = '1';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + 
    CASE 
        WHEN @sql = '' THEN ''
        ELSE '+ '
    END + 'CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ISNULL(' + cols.COLUMN_NAME + ', '''')) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @sql + ' LIKE ''%' + @Find + '%''';

-- Or if you want to add other field types you can use this instead:
--SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE CAST(' + @sql + ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE ''%' + @Find + '%''';

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: This fails for columns with DataType INT or Numeric

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM students_all
WHERE  'left' in (student_name , age ,student_id , class);
```

It will provide you the row where Left is present

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM students_all as t
WHERE t.student_name == 'left'
      OR t.age == 'left'
      OR t.student_id == 'left'
      OR t.class == 'left'
```

There isn't a "fast" way to check every colums at one time, you need to check 1by1 every colum!

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i find this query
SELECT *
  FROM [Table Name]
  WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'value');

but its need to make creating full text catalog and full text search

Answer (score 2):

What i understand is that u want data which have value `left` in any of column of table

For that you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM students_all
WHERE 
      student_name == 'left'
      OR age == 'left'
      OR student_id == 'left'
      OR class == 'left'
```

This will check give you the rows which have at least one column of value `left`

But i you want to get data which contain the word `left` the you need to change all those for conditions in `WHERE` to `COLULMN_NAME LIKE %left%`

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008) is what the OP's trying to refer to.
It requires modification, however, to search only from 1 specific table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM students_all as std
WHERE 
std.student_name = 'left'
OR std.age = 'left'
OR std.student_id = 'left'
OR std.class = 'left'
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [@shA.t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297834/3357935) to allow for column names with spaces.

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = 'TableName';
DECLARE @Find nvarchar(50) = 'SearchText';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql +
    CASE 
        WHEN @sql = '' THEN ''
        ELSE ' OR '
    END + '[' + cols.COLUMN_NAME +']' + ' LIKE ''%' + @Find +'%'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

select @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @sql 
execute(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will search a specific string in all tables, rows and columns of a database, if found results it will return table's name and column's name of that table that contain result in the database. Note that it will return results not only equal to 'StringToFind' but also contain 'StringToFind'. I've tested it with SQL Server 2019.

```
USE NameDatabase; -- Replace 'NameDatabase' with the actual name of the database

-- Create a temporary results table
CREATE TABLE #SearchResults (TableName NVARCHAR(128), ColumnName NVARCHAR(128))

-- Replace 'StringToFind' with the value you want to find
DECLARE @SearchValue NVARCHAR(100) = 'StringToFind';

-- Create CURSOR to iterate through all tables
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name AS TableName, c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id

-- Loop through each table and execute the query
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO #SearchResults (TableName, ColumnName) 
    SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @ColumnName + ''' WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE CAST([' + @ColumnName + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    LIKE ''%' + @SearchValue + '%'')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

SELECT * FROM #SearchResults;

-- Delete the temporary results table
DROP TABLE #SearchResults;
```

If you want to search a Unicode string, you can use the following SQL query.

```
USE NameDatabase; -- Replace 'NameDatabase' with the actual name of the database

-- Create a temporary results table
CREATE TABLE #SearchResults (TableName NVARCHAR(128), ColumnName NVARCHAR(128))

DECLARE @SearchValue NVARCHAR(100) = N'StringToFind';

-- Create CURSOR to iterate through all tables
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name AS TableName, c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id

-- Loop through each table and execute the query
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SqlQuery = N'INSERT INTO #SearchResults (TableName, ColumnName)
    SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', ''' + @ColumnName + ''' WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE [' + @ColumnName + '] COLLATE Vietnamese_CI_AI 
    LIKE N''%' + @SearchValue + '%'')'
    -- Replace Vietnamese_CI_AI with the collation that matches the Unicode string you want to find

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

SELECT * FROM #SearchResults;

-- Delete the temporary results table
DROP TABLE #SearchResults;
```

It can return some error like

```
(0 rows affected)

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type bit is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type int is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type datetime is invalid for COLLATE clause.

(1 row affected)

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type bigint is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type datetime2 is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type decimal is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Msg 447, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Expression type varbinary(max) is invalid for COLLATE clause.
```

but it still returns the results you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from students_all where left (
    student_name
    age
    student_id
    class
```

if all the columns are string type