# Search a query in multiple sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have many tables that contains same column i want to search for a value and return all the line for example

```
Tab1

col1 col2 col3

val1   val2  val3

val7   val8  val9
```

Tab2

```
col1 col2 col3

val4   val2  val5
```

i want the sql syntax that return if i search in my java code for val2 the two lines

```
Tab1

col1   col2  col3

val1   val2  val3
```

and

```
Tab2

col1   col2  col3

val4   val2  val5
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. This is not a coding service but a Q&A website.

Comment: I'd recommend researching [joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a `UNION` between two queries each of which selects the records you want:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Tab1' AS table_name
FROM Tab1
WHERE col2 = 'val2'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Tab2'
FROM Tab2
WHERE col2 = 'val2'
```

If you want to search for `val2` in *any* column, then you can use this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Tab1' AS table_name
FROM Tab1
WHERE col1 = 'val2' OR col2 = 'val2' OR col3 = 'val2'
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Tab2'
FROM Tab2
WHERE col1 = 'val2' OR col2 = 'val2' OR col3 = 'val2'
```

Comment: thank you but i had too much table i can't do it manually is there any procedure that search with information scheme

Comment: I'd add an additional field to both selects to display the table name, such as `'Tab1' AS table_name` so you know which table matched the query.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for the input.  Not sure if my answer is what the OP is after though.

Answer (score 0):

you also can try sp_MSforeachtable and temporary table.

```
    CREATE TABLE #tt(col1 INT,col2 INT,col3 int)
    INSERT INTO #tt
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'select  * from ? where col1=''1'' and OBJECT_ID(''?'') in (OBJECT_ID(''table1''),OBJECT_ID(''table1''),OBJECT_ID(''table1'')) ' 
    SELECT * FROM #tt
```