# Delete data form multiple unknown tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to delete specific data from any tables in my SQL Server. 
DB like this. I want to delete all Romios.

```
Dog.table
(NAME,AGE) = {(Romio,2), (Juliet,3)}

Cat.table
(NAME, Fur) = {(Romio,short), (Trump, bald)}

Cow.table
(Name, Mlik) = {(Romio, 10L), (Obama, 2L)}

Useless.table
(Use1, Use2) = {...}
```

So, I got tables list with the below code:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME =  'NAME'
```

But, the next step doesn't work.

```
DELETE (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME =  'NAME') WHERE Name = 'Romio'
```

Yeah..... I know delete query only works for 1 table. That query has a problem.

How can I make it work?

Comment: you'll need dynamic sql. happy reading! http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Why doesn't the "next step" work?

Comment: Ask the question correctly and that usually leads you to an answer - or at least a direction. You want to delete rows where some column (or maybe specific column) contains the mentioned value. So the first step is to find all occurrences, correct? That has been answered **many** times [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008/19112606).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you don't mind using dynamic `TSQL`, i.e. using `EXEC`

```
DECLARE @StrQuery nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @StrQuery = ISNULL(@StrQuery, '') + 'DELETE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE NAME = ''Romio''  ' FROM information_schema.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME =  'NAME'
EXEC(@StrQuery)
```