# How can I return a distinct count of a variable for all tables in my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database with 60+ tables, almost all of which are populated with a CLIENTID field. I want to count the number of unique client IDs in each table.

The results I'm looking for are:

```
TABLE_NAME; CLIENTID_COUNT
dbo.HISTORY; 650
dbo.VISITS; 596
dbo.SALES; 1053
...; ...
```

This seems like it should be so simple but I've been playing around with cursors for hours and can't figure this one out. Please help!

Comment: Can you share your code and the results you have gotten so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a string by searching all tables in SQL Server Management Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008)

Comment: Essentially, there are system stored procedures which will list all tables. Use that as the basis and see the suggestion from @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_RESULTS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_RESULTS
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_RESULTS
(
TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX),
CLIENTCNT BIGINT
)

DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_PROCESS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_PROCESS
SELECT * INTO #TEMP_PROCESS FROM sys.tables 

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [#TEMP_PROCESS])
BEGIN
SET @TABLENAME = (SELECT TOP 1 [NAME] FROM [#TEMP_PROCESS])
SET @command = ('SELECT ''' + @TABLENAME + ''', COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTID) AS CLIENTCNT FROM ' + @TABLENAME)
SELECT @command
INSERT INTO #TEMP_RESULTS
EXEC(@command) 

DELETE FROM [#TEMP_PROCESS] WHERE [NAME] = @TABLENAME
END

SELECT * FROM [#TEMP_RESULTS]
```

Comment: I think the insert should actually be "SELECT ''' + @TABLENAME + ''', COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTID) AS CLIENTCNT FROM ' +  @TABLENAME"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column is exactly ClientId in every table, you should be able to use this as is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #clientId
CREATE TABLE #clientId
(
    TableName nvarchar(1000),
    ClientIdCount bigint
)

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @CurrentQuery nvarchar(2000);

DECLARE result_cursor CURSOR local fast_forward FOR
SELECT DISTINCT
    '['+TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']'
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME = 'ClientId'

OPEN result_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor into @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

SET @CurrentQuery = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', COUNT(DISTINCT ClientId) FROM ' + @TableName
--print @CurrentQuery

INSERT INTO
    #clientId
(
    TableName,
    ClientIdCount
)
EXEC(@CurrentQuery)

FETCH NEXT FROM result_cursor into @TableName
END
--end loop

--clean up
CLOSE result_cursor
DEALLOCATE result_cursor

GO

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #clientId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic sql.

This will read through your system tables, find those that have a ClientID column, and build the text of a query that's in the general shape of 'Select Count(DISTINCT ClientID)' from each table.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery as nvarchar(max) = ''

------------------------------------
-- GET THE TABLES THAT HAVE A CLIENTID FROM SCHEMA
SELECT @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + qryTxt FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'SELECT ''' + tables.name + ''', COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENTID) FROM ' + tables.name + ' UNION ' AS qryTxt
    FROM sys.columns left join sys.tables on columns.object_id = tables.object_id where columns.name = CLIENTID AND isnull(tables.name, '') <> '') subquery

------------------------------------
-- REMOVE THE LAST 'UNION' KEYWORD FROM SQLQUERY 
SET @SQLQuery = left(@sqlQuery, len(@sqlQuery) - 5)

------------------------------------
-- EXECUTE
execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: LOL you and I posted very similar solutions just seconds apart. :)

Comment: Woot!  That's a compliment for me.

Answer (score 1):

I really dislike cursors and loops. Even though this is not going to be much difference for a performance perspective I like to share how you can leverage the system tables and dynamic sql to avoid using a cursor, while loop or temp tables for something like this.

This code is literally all you need to to do this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select TableName = ''' + t.name + ''', ClientID_Count = count(distinct clientID)
from ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' UNION ALL ' 
from sys.tables t
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name = 'clientID'

select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) --removes the last UNION ALL

select @SQL
--once your comfortable the dynamic sql is correct just uncomment the line below.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar pattern to other answers here, but this is how I would tackle it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#Tables', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Tables;
SELECT ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1),
    SchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
    TableName = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]),
    ColumnName = name,
    DistinctCount = 0
    INTO #Tables
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE name = 'CLIENTID';

DECLARE @ID INT = 1,
    @MaxID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Tables);
WHILE @ID < @MaxID
BEGIN;
    DECLARE @SQLCommand VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @SQLCommand = FORMATMESSAGE('
UPDATE #Tables SET DistinctCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT %s) FROM %s.%s
    )
    WHERE ID = %i;',
        QUOTENAME(ColumnName), QUOTENAME(SchemaName), QUOTENAME(TableName), ID)
        FROM #Tables
        WHERE ID = @ID;
    EXEC (@SQLCommand);
    SET @ID += 1;
END;

SELECT *
    FROM #Tables;
```