# How do I find in which table Data has my given value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I need is to find out which tables have certain column data. It doesn't matter which column it belongs in, I just don't know which table to look at since there are a lot of tables.

Please let me know if you have ideas. Thanks.

**Note:** I should search in XML columns as well.

This is what I have tried. It did not work, please suggest better ideas for me to try.

```
    USE DATABASE_NAME
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'SEARCH_TEXT'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
```

Comment: ` It did not work` means what? By the way, aggregation using a scalra variable is not safe, it is not guaranteed to work in the way you expect, use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead. Also you should quote all table and column names with `quotename` instead of trying to do it yourself. You may also want to filter to `n/varchar` and `xml` columns only

Comment: So what exactly didn't work? You've not quoted the column name prior to `from` so if any column exists with spaces etc it will break. I'd also recommend a top(1) otherwise you'll find all rows in a table that matches which won't tell you anything you don't already know, and specific columns matching the data type you're looking for.
Basically though, I tested with some tables and known data, it works.

Comment: I have used the approach in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361062/632537).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a string by searching all tables in SQL Server Management Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008)

Comment: Actually I have tried many options which are listed in the - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008/27361062#27361062   - But none of them are returning response, even i waited for 15 minutes, still no response

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to the code you already had to include the XML datatype and cast the XML into NVARCHAR (MAX) in the WHERE clause and in the table variable.

```
USE DATABASE_NAME
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'SEARCH_TEXT'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(max))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' +     
            QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) ), 'IsMSShipped' ) = 0 )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 
                'decimal','xml') AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName )

    IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Results
        EXEC
        (
            'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''','+ 
            'cast('+    @ColumnName+  ' as nvarchar(max))'
            +'FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
            ' WHERE cast( ' +  @ColumnName + ' as nvarchar(max)) LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
        )
    END
   END    
END
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried the above query and I waited almost 15 minutes, still no response/result so i have to cancel the query.