# How to check, find and see the values of a specific column inside of a big database with many tables, if the column actually exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of tables inside some database of SQL Server and I think that some of those tables have some specific column that, I want to check if it exists and also see the values inside, if it actually exists.

I guess that the column was named like: ‘’Status’’

Please, consider that I don't have any idea about what are the values that maybe exist inside of this supposed column or even the kind of it.

Database name: PrincipalGroup

I won't say the name of the tables, because I don’t think it's feasible to write all the tables in this query, because there are many.

So, the point is: how can I query this by the easiest and simplest way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a string by searching all tables in SQL Server Management Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757263/find-a-string-by-searching-all-tables-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008)

Comment: You should be able to adapt this reply to your specific needs or find your own alternative with simple searching. I have to wonder why a column of the same name and datatype exists in many tables inside your database - removing / reducing the amount of duplicated information is a goal of proper normalization. Perhaps it is better to fix that problem if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query that will produce a list of SQL statements you can then execute to "see the values inside" each table that contains the column named `Status`, and obviously tweak to your specific requirements.

```
select Concat('select distinct ', QUOTENAME(table_name, ''''), ' , [Status] from ', QuoteName(table_name))
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where COLUMN_NAME = 'Status'
```

Comment: But by this query I need to speciffying the tables of database, right?

Comment: No, have you run it? It will list you only the tables that contain the named column, eg Status.