# Select Table Based on The Number in the Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of tables in a database: MainTable1, MainTable2, MainTable3. There are also other tables being added with different unique names at different times. Each day a new "MainTable" is generated and a larger numeric value added to the end of the name to indicate it is the newest. I would like to write a query that references the latest MainTable based on the max number, however, I haven't been able to find any relevant information from prior posts on the forum with the max() function incorporated. This link was the closest, but I wasn't able to follow the rabbit hole to incorporate the main answer [SQL : Select a table name containing specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433729/sql-select-a-table-name-containing-specific-string)

For example, if tomorrow MainTable4 is added I'd like to query against it in a select statement without having to manually change the numeric value. Is this possible in SSMS?

```
Select * From [Database].[dbo].max(cast(
```

Comment: Your life and code would be much simpler if you use *one* MainTable with an extra column for the date.

Comment: The tables in `from` part must be fixed. You cannot have any functions or anything like that. Either you need to use dynamic SQL for your query, or do some other kludges like a view that you change every day, a synonym or something similar.

Comment: Even though (as others have pointed out) this is a pretty poor way to implement the recording of daily data, one option could be to create (and recreate) a VIEW each time a new "Main" table is created.  The VIEW could be called "MainTableLatest", and each time you recreate the view you just change it to ``SELECT * FROM MainTable#`` (where # is the latest "MainTable" number).  Then all of your general queries - that need to always get data from the most recent "MainTable" - would just use ``SELECT ...<columns> ... from MainTableLatest``

Comment: I’m not the owner of the existing process, so I can’t control naming convention for new tables. I know it’s not ideal, so I appreciate the constructive feedback on the problem at hand.

Comment: Take a peek at https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/sqlserver/synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using dynamic SQL to generate a query that references the latest "MainTable" based on the maximum numeric value in the table names

```
DECLARE @LatestMainTable NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @LatestMainTable = (
SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'MainTable%'
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 10, LEN(TABLE_NAME) - 9) AS 
INT) DESC)
```

This helps you identify the latest table name then

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@LatestMainTable)

-- Execute the dynamic SQL query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

This uses the information in the first query to perform an actual SELECT operation on the latest table.
You need both queries  to achieve the desired outcome of dynamically selecting data from the latest "MainTable" in your database.

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to implement this.  The correct way is to add a column with the date.  EVERY SINGLE SQL PLATFORM will work better (faster) this way.  You will need to create the indexes. Creating a new table every day will not make anything easier and many things harder.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a bad database design in my opinion, but here is one way to do it.

You can execute a Transact-SQL statement that has been built dynamically with name of the table as follows:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @MaxNum INT;

select @MaxNum = COUNT(*) FROM sys.all_objects WHERE TYPE = 'U' AND NAME LIKE 'MainTable%'

SET @SQLString = CONCAT(N'select * from MainTable',@MaxNum);  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

More info and examples on [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)