# Search All tables in database where a string matches and get table structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string and I want to search that string in all the `tables` of `Database`.

Fortunately, I have the Query to search in all the tables of the database and get me the result which is quite impressive.

```
USE DATABASE_NAME
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'SEARCH_TEXT'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END    
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results
```

And I got the result

[image]

***The Problem: *** I want the third column with this result and that is `primary_key` column

Basically I have to run the updation task on this result, so I want `primary key` for my `where` clause to apply on.

So please update this query and help me to get the third column (primary_key column) with this result

PS: if anyone has another solution to this problem most welcome

The basic problem in simple words is:

A search of a specific string in database tables and update the values of the column value where the specific string matches.

Comment: Where are you guys finding this ancient code? It's almost identical to the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015993/search-a-database-for-text-and-int-is-returning-error-the-multi-part-identifier) from two hours ago.

Comment: Yes Code might be the same, but the problem is different that I want to resolve with this

Comment: I removed the tag for Oracle's PL/SQL as this is clearly T-SQL for SQL Server

Comment: You can try to use the DataGrip to solve this task: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/full-text-search-for-databases.html

Comment: @ScrappyCoco i have to write a corn job for database

Comment: You assume that every table has a primary key composed of a single column. Is that safe? But the logic can be easily extended by fetching the primary key column name (here is your assumption) when you establish the identity of the table in your loop.

Comment: @SMor if you could help me to write the T-Sql that would be good, I am naive in T-SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
USE springhibernate
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'James'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630), PrimaryColumnName nvarchar(370))
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @PrimaryColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )
    IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @PrimaryColumnName = (
                SELECT  MIN(QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.COLUMN_NAME))
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cd
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cd.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE
                QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) = @TableName

                AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
            )
    END
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @PrimaryColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630), LEFT(' + @PrimaryColumnName + ', 3630)
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630), NULL   
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END
    END    
END
SELECT * FROM @Results
```

Comment: Thank you, You just same my alot of time.

Comment: Welcome, always happy to help with SQL 

Answer (score 1):

I want to fetch the primaryKey column also so that I can run following Query

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET <COLUMN_NAME> = REPLACE(<COLUMN_NAME>, '<REPLACE_STRING>', '') where <PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME> = PRIMARY_KEY;
```

So @Tarun Query help me to get
* TABLE_NAME
* COLUMN_NAME
* PRIMARY_KEY
But I need one more data  `PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME` So I updated little bit

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = '%JAMES%'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630), PrimaryKeyId nvarchar(370), PrimaryColumnName nvarchar(370))
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @PrimaryKeyId nvarchar(128),@PrimaryColumnName nvarchar(128) ,@SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )
    IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @PrimaryColumnName = (
                SELECT  MIN(QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.COLUMN_NAME))
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cd
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cd.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE
                QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) = @TableName
                AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
            )
    END
    BEGIN
        SET @PrimaryKeyId = (
                SELECT  MIN(QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.COLUMN_NAME))
                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cd
        join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cd.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE
                QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(cd.TABLE_NAME) = @TableName

                AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
            )
    END
    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )
        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @PrimaryKeyId IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630), LEFT(' + @PrimaryKeyId + ', 3630), ''' + @PrimaryColumnName +'''
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630), NULL, ''' + @PrimaryColumnName +'''   
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END
    END    
END
SELECT * FROM @Results
```

And this is able to get

```
ColumnName | ColumnValue | PrimaryKeyId | PrimaryColumnName
```